# How to add watcher to JIRA ticket using JIRA python API

Tags: python, python-2.7, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am using JIRA python API to create JIRA tickets from my code. The code looks like below

```
from jira.client import JIRA
def create_jira_issue(jira, summary, description, status):

    project = getattr(settings,'jira_project_' + status)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    pm_jira_dict = {
        'project': {'key': getattr(settings,'jira_project_' + status)},
        'summary': summary,
        'description': description,
        'issuetype': {'name': settings.jira_issuetype},
        'assignee':{'name': settings.jira_assignee},
        'timetracking':{'originalEstimate': settings.jira_timetracking},
        'duedate':now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    }

    new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=pm_jira_dict)
    return new_issue
```

Now I want to add a Watcher to this ticket. How can I add it here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that the watcher you want to add is in the variable "watcher":
Add

```
jira.add_watcher(new_issue.id,watcher)
```

at the end of your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

jira.add_watcher(issue, jira._get_user_id('user'))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).